# How to combine 0xFF & 0x000000?

Tags: android

I want to use these two values (opacity (0xE6 / #E6) and color (0x000000 / #000000) to configure the color of a widget.

This works:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_relative, "setBackgroundColor", 0xE6000000);
```

But I would like to have something like this, where I can store both values in a separate Int (eg. int int_opacity & int int_color:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_relative, "setBackgroundColor", int_opacity + int_color);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can combine it:

```
int int_color = 0x000000;
int int_opacity = 0xE6;

int combined_color = int_color | (int_opacity << 24)
```